# Renaming a table while leaving the existing triggers behind

Tags: database, oracle, table-rename

A decision was made to join a couple of existing tables together in a cluster.

This obviously means that the tables need to be recreated so they can be clustered together, however the existing data should be preserved.

Naturally I assume the procedure would be something along the lines of:

- Back up existing table under a different name (via a rename or something)
- Create a new clustered table under the old name
- Copy all the data from the backup table into the newly created one

However the current table has quite a few triggers assigned to it (and correct me if I'm wrong here but) when I'll execute the rename operation on that table I assume all the triggers assigned to it by order of convenience will refactor themselves to match the new name.

The perfect scenario in this case would probably be for the triggers to temporarily "detach" themselves from the table once it gets renamed (still point to the old table name which would not exist at that point), and then would be once again functional when the newly created clustered table appears.

However I'm not sure if this is possible.

**So the question here is:** Can I leave the triggers behind when renaming the table, or should I deal with them manually?

Comment: Couldn't you just copy the old tables as backup and then alter the existing tables, copying the old data back in after altering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct: When you rename a table its associated triggers will still refer to the same table. ( Note the trigger names themselves will not be renamed ).

I had this problem so I wrote a script that utilised `DMBS_METADATA.GET_DDL` to extract the trigger(s) code for the table. The process was:

For each table `T`:

1. For each trigger, constraint, check constraints, non-pk indexes on
   `T` extract to DDL using `DMBS_METADATA.GET_DDL`
2. Rename the table `T` to `OLD_TABLE_NAME`
3. Create the new table ( you could use CTAS if you want to migrate
   data )
4. Drop ( or rename ) all triggers, constraints, indexes from
   `OLD_TABLE_NAME`
5. Run extracted DDL to recreate trigger, constraint, indexes on new
   table

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably have to build a script like that.
Another thing to note is that if I create views for the tables and move the triggers onto the views instead of the table, I can rename the table and the view will not follow suit and the triggers will be somewhat detached from the now renamed table.
Afterwards when I create a new table under the same name as the old one, the view will snap onto it along with the triggers.

Answer (score 4):

The triggers do not reference the table by name, only the DDL that creates them does that. They reference the internal identifier of the table, so when you rename the table the trigger does not change at all. However, if you reverse-engineer the DDL for the trigger from the database the code will of course reference the new name of the table. Code inside the trigger is not changed if it specifically references the table name, but that's hopefully not the case.

So of course the triggers cannot be disassociated from the table, and the best you can do is export the DDL for the triggers, indexes privileges etc..

Similarly indexes do not directly reference table names.

It sounds like an underlying problem here is that you are not using a code repository, because that would enable you to just rerun the scripts required for granting privileges, creating indexes, applying trigger etc after renaming the table and dropping the associated schema items.